# Purpose of ProviderUserName column in DotNetOpenAuth sample

Tags: asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth, asp.net-4.5, google-openid

I've started an ASP.NET web site in Visual Studio using a Microsoft pre-defined template.  This is to help me learn about OpenID within ASP.NET.

Inside the included SQL database within the sample site, there is a table called `UsersOpenAuthAccounts` that contains a column called `ProviderUserName`.

Can anyone tell me the purpose of this column?  In my tests, this seems to store the username that I would log into an OpenID site with (e.g. my Google username - my email address).  However, I also see that the `ProviderUserId` column holds the `IAuthenticationResponse.ClaimedIdentifier` value, e.g.

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AIt................g3c
```

...which would be used to identify the user against the OpenID provider for future requests.

Therefore, is there any point in including the `ProviderUserName` column?  It's not actually used anywhere else within Microsoft's sample site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProviderUserName is... a bad idea (IMO).

The OpenID Claimed Identifier is the right string to check for return users. It reduces security to use anything else, including email address. If you're only interested in OpenID logins then you may want to just throw out the ASP.NET provided code and use DotNetOpenAuth's `OpenIdRelyingParty` directly and deal with the users table yourself. It will be about as simple as your current code, but without the unnecessary columns.

What the ASP.NET team's additional column and façade classes give you is the ability to mix OpenID logins with OAuth logins, which allow you to accept Twitter and Facebook accounts at your site as well. OAuth wasn't designed to be an authentication protocol, so those who use it have to make up their own idea of a username. In order for that to be globally unique, it must be prefixed by the provider who is issuing that username. So you have ProviderName ("twitter" or "google") and a ProviderUsername which is the username (or user id perhaps) of the account from the OAuth service provider.

Comment: "use DotNetOpenAuth's OpenIdRelyingParty directly and deal with the users table yourself".  Yes this is my plan, as I am integrating OpenId functionality into an existing application that already has authorization taken care of.  Thanks for a very clear answer.